# SwiftUI: Drag and Drop Item Preview Bug?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

[image: Preview Bug]

As one can see in the gif, when draging an item, it somehow is clipped in a way that views within the item which extend the width/ height are cut off and some white background is added behind the rounded corners.

Here is my basic implementation.

```
struct ReorderableForEach<Content: View>: View {

    var items: [Picture]
    let content: (Int) -> Content
    let move: (IndexSet, Int) -> Void

    @State private var current: Picture?

    init(
        items: [Picture],
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content,
        move: @escaping (IndexSet, Int) -> Void
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.content = content
        self.move = move
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(zip(items.indices, items)), id: \.1) { index, item in
            content(index)
                .onDrop(
                    of: [.text],
                    delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(
                        item: item,
                        list: items,
                        current: $current
                    ) { from, to in
                        withAnimation {
                            move(from, to)
                        }
                    }
                )
                .if(item.status != .standard, transform: { content in
                    content
                        .onDrag {
                            current = item
                            let provider = NSItemProvider(object: "\(item.id)" as NSString)
                            return provider
                        }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or am i doing anything wrong? Any help is appreciated.